# change custom listview item

Tags: android, listview

Infact i have a listview and it has "two images + two Textviews" as an item.

What i exactly want to do is that i want to change the textview's text when user clicks the image.

`public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{`

```
`ViewHolder holder;`
`ArrayList<Object> itemList;`

`public Activity context;`
`public LayoutInflater inflater;`

`public ListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<Object> itemList) {`
    `super();`

    `this.context = context;`
    `this.itemList = itemList;`

    `this.inflater =` `(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`
`}`

`@Override`
`public int getCount() {`
    `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`
    `return itemList.size();`
`}`

`@Override`
`public Object getItem(int position) {`
    `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`
    `return itemList.get(position);`
`}`

`@Override`
`public long getItemId(int position) {`
    `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`
    `return 0;`
`}`

`public static class ViewHolder`
`{`
    `ImageView plus;`
    `ImageView minus;`
    `TextView question;`
    `TextView score;`
`}`

`@Override`
`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {`
    `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`


    `if(convertView==null)`
    `{`
        `holder = new ViewHolder();`
        `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);`

        `holder.plus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);`
        `holder.minus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);`

        `holder.plus.setOnClickListener(this);`
        `holder.minus.setOnClickListener(this);`

        `holder.question = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);`
        `holder.score = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.score);`

                    `convertView.setTag(holder);`
    `}`
    `else`
        `holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();`

    `ItemBean bean = (ItemBean) itemList.get(position);`

    `holder.minus.setImageResource(bean.getminus());`
    `holder.plus.setImageResource(bean.getplus());`
    `holder.question.setText(bean.getquestion());`
    `holder.score.setText(bean.getscore());`

    `return convertView;`
`}`

`@Override`
`public void onClick(View v) {`
    `switch(v.getId()) {`
        `case R.id.minus:`
        `{`

            `int score = Integer.getInteger(holder.score.getText().toString());`
            `holder.score.setText(Integer.toString(score-1));`
            `break;`
        `}`
        `case R.id.plus:`
        `{`

            `int score = Integer.getInteger(holder.score.getText().toString());`
            `holder.score.setText(Integer.toString(score+1));`
            `break;`
        `}`
    `}}`
```

`}`

I am getting null pointer exception.
What i think the problem is, program is not able to understand that which textview it sould target, like there are multiple items in this listview, and each item contains this Score Textview item.

Plz help me out!!

Comment: is the problem with click listener?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to set the onClickListener for the ListItem when you create it. You can then specify what that ListItem does when it's clicked, so you can tell it to change it's TextView text.

Here's a really good tutorial on creating that set up:
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1351248&q=handling-android-listview-onitemclick-event

Answer (score 1):

Instead of convertView.setTag(holder);holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();`
use convertView.setId(holder); and holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getId();

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everyone.

But the solution to my problem was pretty much simple and smart.I have resolved.

i have attached the holder using holder.minus.setTag( holder ); against each item (button/imageview) of each row of listview and then in Onclick Listener of that particular button/imageView i am using holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();   to use that specific Holder for that item of ListView :) Have Fun

@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                    holder.score = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.score);
                    holder.question = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
                    holder.plus = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);


                    holder.minus = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
```

holder.plus.setTag( holder );
                        holder.minus.setTag( holder );

```
                    holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

                            String test =holder.score.getText().toString();

                    }
                        }
                    });


                    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

                            String test =holder.score.getText().toString();

                                                    }
                    });


                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:

                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.heading, null);
                    holder.score = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    holder.score.setText(mData.get(position));
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        switch (type) 
        {
            case TYPE_ITEM:

                String temp = mData.get(position);

                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:

                holder.score.setText(mData.get(position));

                break;
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: "TYPE_SEPARATOR" "TYPE_ITEM" where you declared that varible

Answer (score 0):

Dont use else replace below code

```
`if(convertView==null)`
    `{`
        `holder = new ViewHolder();`
        `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);`

        `holder.plus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);`
        `holder.minus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);`

        `holder.plus.setOnClickListener(this);`
        `holder.minus.setOnClickListener(this);`

        `holder.question = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);`
        `holder.score = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.score);`

                    `convertView.setTag(holder);`
    `}
        `holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();`

    `ItemBean bean = (ItemBean) itemList.get(position);`

    `holder.minus.setImageResource(bean.getminus());`
    `holder.plus.setImageResource(bean.getplus());`
    `holder.question.setText(bean.getquestion());`
    `holder.score.setText(bean.getscore());`

    `return convertView;`
`}`
```

Comment: it doesnt make any difference

Comment: use normal ViewHolder instead of static ViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not assigning **onClick** listener to any of your view in your Base adapter.

Second, instead of using **onClick** event for views with in the row, I would suggest you to use **OnItemClickListener** for your ListLiew. This pretty much straight forward and better to use for row item clicks

for example:

```
private OnItemClickListener lstClick = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {

        //do whatever you want here
    }
};
```

and set it to your ListView as:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(lstClick);
```

Comment: OnItemClickListener is for ListActivity, and i am working on Activity instead..still thanks!!

Comment: OnItemClickListener is for ListView and ListActivity is a derived form of ListView with an Activity. So my suggestion is still valid. You may use OnItemClickListener for ListView.

Comment: For more info, read [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_overview)

Comment: ok..thanks..i have found another solution to this i have posted.